# WPF ComboBox reloading and setting displayite which is an object an object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been working in a bespoke control based upon the WPF ComboBox

code below

```
enter code here<UserControl x:Class="wpfColorCombo.ColorPicker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="32" d:DesignWidth="190">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LoadedValue">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Width="10"
                       Height="10"
                       Margin="5"
                       Background="Aqua"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Aqua"
                       Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="colorPickerCombo"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FontColors}"
              DropDownClosed="colourPickerCombo_DropDownClosed"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedFontColor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              Loaded="colourPickerCombo_Loaded">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="10"
                               Height="10"
                               Margin="5"
                               Background="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox> 
</Grid>
```

The controls code behind:

```
    public partial class ColorPicker : UserControl
{

    public ColorPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new viewModelColorPicker();
    }
}
```

Nothing unusual here except when I come to reload the control with with saved data.  I seem to be unable to find a means to get the displayed.  I have looked for the last half day for a solution and the nearest I have come is based upon a similar problem in a Grid control.  The solution there was to assign the windows resource in this case LoadedValue to the content.  In a ComboBox I have Text.  I have tried to utilize TextBlock but without a stack panel to aid lay outs I am stuck.

Any help that may get me closer is good :)

Cheers Angry Bobb

Comment: Also I have no idea how I show my historical searches in this site.  Last time I got a rude response because I did not show.  Please don't assume no reference is no work.  Very Angry Bobb

Comment: what is the problem actually? That the displayed items are objects, not properties or something else?

Comment: Where is the code you are using to reload the control? And where are the properties being set?

Comment: Will post the whole of the control's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer after much fartting about is

```
this.SelectedColor = this.FontColors.Where(a => a.Name == "Black").FirstOrDefault();
```

All because the selection is the selection of a value in the supplying collection and not setting a value to display.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues like this, mostly these problem occurs when you overwrite the bounded instance.

Like, when you load the data, *(for example with xmlserializer)* a new instance of the `FontColors` will overwrite the old one. The combobox is still bounded to the old instance, so the new one doesn't show up.

So, you probably need to reassign/bind the `ItemsSource` of the `Combobox` after loading.

Comment: I will go try that via the code behind, I will also poke the SelectedValue too if needed.

Comment: Jeroen I have just made the code more concise which may not have solved the issue but does incorporate the suggestion of ObservableCollections.  Please review the code.  I can see the get in SelectedColour in the ViewModel returning a value on request.  I simply do not see how to make it display in the the control on load.

Comment: What if you add `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor?

Comment: I see the xaml is refering to: `ColorPicker.View.ColorPicker`, Can't see the code behind.

Comment: Don't be concerned with     ColorPicker.View.ColorPicker it is not relevant.  I have corrected the problem to ensure no further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code behind

```
public class viewModelColorPicker : ViewModelBase 
{
    modelFont colours = new modelFont();

    public viewModelColorPicker()
    {
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FontColor> fontColours;
    public ObservableCollection<FontColor> FontColours
    {
        get 
        {
            fontColours = colours.AvalibleColours;
            return fontColours;
        }
    }

    private FontColor selectedColour = new FontColor("Black",Brushes.Black); 
    public FontColor SelectedColour
    {
        get 
        {
            selectedColour = colours.SelectedColor.Coalesce(new FontColor("Black",Brushes.Black));                
            return selectedColour; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref selectedColour, value, "SelectedColour");
            colours.SelectedColor = value;
        }
    }

}
```

These three classes are the model

```
    public class modelFont : ViewModelBase 
{

    ObservableCollection<FontColor> availableColours = new ObservableCollection<FontColor>();

    public modelFont()
    {
        AvailableColors AvCol = new AvailableColors();
        availableColours = AvCol.GetFontColorsList().ToObservableCollection();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FontColor> AvalibleColours
    {
        get { return availableColours; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this.availableColours, value, "AvalibleColours"); }
    }

    private FontColor selectedColor;
    public FontColor SelectedColor
    {
        get { return selectedColor; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this.selectedColor, value, "SelectedColor"); }
    }
}


public class FontColor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }

        public FontColor(string name, SolidColorBrush brush)
        {
            Name = name;
            Brush = brush;
        }

        public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            FontColor p = obj as FontColor;
            if ((System.Object)p == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (this.Name == p.Name) && (this.Brush.Equals(p.Brush));
        }

        public bool Equals(FontColor p)
        {
            if ((object)p == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (this.Name == p.Name) && (this.Brush.Equals(p.Brush));
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "FontColor [Color=" + this.Name + ", " + this.Brush.ToString() + "]";
        }
    }
}



class AvailableColors : List<FontColor>
    {
        #region Conversion Utils Static Methods
        public static FontColor GetFontColor(SolidColorBrush b)
        {
            AvailableColors brushList = new AvailableColors();
            return brushList.GetFontColorByBrush(b);
        }

        public static FontColor GetFontColor(string name)
        {
            AvailableColors brushList = new AvailableColors();
            return brushList.GetFontColorByName(name);
        }

        public static FontColor GetFontColor(Color c)
        {
            return AvailableColors.GetFontColor(new SolidColorBrush(c));
        }

        public static int GetFontColorIndex(FontColor c)
        {
            AvailableColors brushList = new AvailableColors();
            int idx = 0;
            SolidColorBrush colorBrush = c.Brush;

            foreach (FontColor brush in brushList)
            {
                if (brush.Brush.Color.Equals(colorBrush.Color))
                {
                    break;
                }

                idx++;
            }

            return idx;
        }
        #endregion

        public AvailableColors()
            : base()
        {
            this.Init();
        }

        public FontColor GetFontColorByName(string name)
        {
            FontColor found = null;
            foreach (FontColor b in this)
            {
                if (b.Name == name)
                {
                    found = b;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return found;
        }

        public FontColor GetFontColorByBrush(SolidColorBrush b)
        {
            FontColor found = null;
            foreach (FontColor brush in this)
            {
                if (brush.Brush.Color.Equals(b.Color))
                {
                    found = brush;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return found;
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            Type brushesType = typeof(Colors);
            var properties = brushesType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                string name = prop.Name;
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)(prop.GetValue(null, null)));
                this.Add(new FontColor(name, brush));
            }

        }
    }
```

These are the helper classes

```
    public static class Ext_CollectionExtensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<DataRow> ToObservableCollection(this DataTable coll)
    {
        var c = new ObservableCollection<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow e in coll.Rows)
            c.Add(e);
        return c;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this List<T> ListOfT)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> returned = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (var itm in ListOfT)
        {
            returned.Add(itm);
        }
        return returned;
    }
}

    public static class Ext_Object
{
    public static T Coalesce<T>(this T obj, params T[] args)
    {
        if (obj != null || Convert.IsDBNull(obj))
            return obj;

        foreach (T arg in args)
        {
            if (arg != null || Convert.IsDBNull(obj))
                return arg;
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

I have modified the code to be more concise.  I did not write the original which I did not feel help in the solving of this problem because it was overly complex and verbose.

Comment: For binding to `ComboBoxes` you should use the `ObservableCollection<T>`. The `ComboBox` will update itself when the collection changes.. So change the `ReadOnlyCollection<FontColor>` to `ObservableCollection<FontColor>`.

Comment: You talked about reloading etc. Where is that? Are you re-assigning the `ReadOnlyCollection<FontColor> roFontColors`? Instead of assigning, you could `Clear()` it and use something like a `AddRange(loadedItems);`

Comment: Point 1)  private ReadOnlyCollection<FontColor> roFontColors; becomes private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<FontColor> roFontColor;  I think this was what you indicated plus the code in the constructor.